# What to keep in mind when partitioning external hard drive with both encrypted ext4 and unencrypted NTFS?

Tags: windows, partitioning, external-hard-drive, ntfs, dm-crypt

I have an external hard drive that will be partitioned with two partitions, using GPT:

1. ext4 filesystem on a dm-crypt-encrypted partition
2. NTFS filesystem on an unencrypted partition

The ext4 filesystem will be mounted only from computers that I control, so I have no concerns about it.

The NTFS filesystem will be mounted by various Windows machines. At least in the past, Windows [didn’t support multiple partitions](https://superuser.com/a/271275/1063486). Does it matter which partition comes first? Is there a way to prevent Windows from offering the user to format the encrypted partition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Older Windows versions didn't support multiple partitions on flash drives, but USB disks (HDDs or SSDs) were always fully supported (where by "always" I mean "at least since Windows 7, maybe earlier"). Therefore order of partitions doesn't matter, it will just work.

Windows should ignore the encrypted partition. It will appear as RAW in *Disk Management* and anybody with administrative privileges will be able to format it. There's no certain way to stop them, because physical access to a device ultimately gives you full control over it. You *could* try to mitigate it by setting *boot* and *esp* flags on the partition. Windows should disable most management options for such partitions in *Disk Management*.

Comment: To be clear, many of the flags such as _boot_ and _esp_ are exclusively a parted/GParted invention and don't exist in other partitioning tools. They internally just cause parted to choose different "partition type GUIDs". With other partitioning tools, selecting a type GUID that's different from Windows' usual "MS Basic Data" is a good start.

Comment: Sure, if someone really wants to format it, there’s no way to prevent them. I’ll set the correct type GUID and check next time on a Windows computer that it doesn’t show up as an unknown drive.